# how to change the date format 20200219 to 2020Feb19 and use it as a filename in automator?

Tags: automator

I'm doing a simple "Image to PDF" service on automator.
The output file requires a name so I put the name as a "."
I then rename the file to a date and the result is 20200219..pdf

1. I would like the file name to be 2020Feb19..pdf
2. It will be even better if I can remove the extra "." in the filename and make the final filename 2020Feb19.pdf.

I can't seem to find the option to change the date format in automator from 20200219 to 2020Feb19.
I can't seem to find a way to remove the extra "." in the filename.
Do I need a script for that?
Would appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: They put that naming convention in so that it will be sorted chronologically (Jan-Dec) when you sort by name.  If you do it your way, it will be August will come before Feb., Mar., May, etc.  You're getting the second dot (.) because you added it in.  It will automatically add the extention with the dot (.pdf).

Comment: It probably would have been helpful for you to include your **Automator** _workflow_, and without it all I can do if offer a way of renaming a _file_ named e.g., `20200219..pdf` to `2020Feb19.pdf` using **Terminal** or if in **Automator** a **Run Shell Script** _action_. The following _shell commands_ are a proof of concept: `f='20200219..pdf' && touch "$f" && mv -nv "$f" "$(date -jf '%Y%m%d' "${f%..*}" '+%Y%b%d').${f##*.}"` _returns_ `20200219..pdf -> 2020Feb19.pdf` _if_ `2020Feb19.pdf` doesn't already exist. So if you copy and paste that in **Terminal** you'll see first hand it works.